# Automate process for merging CSV files in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to work with 12 different csv files, that are stored in datafolder. I have a function that opens each file separately (openFile) and performs a specific calculation on the data. I then want to be able to apply a function to each file. The names of the files are all similar to this: UOG_001-AC_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv . The code below shows how I was planning to read the files into the openFile function:

```
for file in os.listdir(DATA_PATH + 'datafolder/'):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        abs_path = os.path.abspath(DATA_PATH + 'datafolder/' + file)
        print(abs_path)
        data = openFile(abs_path)
        data2 = someFunction(data)
```

I need to merge specific files, which have the same two letters in the file name. At the end I should have 6 files instead of 12. The files are not stored in the order that they need to be merged in datafolder as this will eventually lead to being used for a larger number of files. The files all have the same header

Am I able to supply a list of the two letters that are the key words in the file to use in regex? e.g.

```
 list = ['AC', 'FO', 'CK', 'OR', 'RS', 'IK']
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this with or without regex?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass command line parameters to your program?

Comment: why dont you simply loop over that list  with and use of `str.startswith('AC')` or with `in`

Answer (score 0):

You could walk through the file tree and, then based on the first two letters of the file name, save each pair of files that need to be merged.

```
fileList = {'AC':[], 'FO':[], 'CK':[], 'OR':[], 'RS':[], 'IK':[]}
for file in os.listdir(DATA_PATH + 'datafolder/'):
     if file.endswith('.csv'): #Ensure we are looking at csv
        #Add the file to its correct bucket based off of the letters in name
        fileList[extractTwoLettersFromFileName(file)].append(file)

for twoLetters, files in fileList.items():
       mergeFiles(files)
```

I did not provide implementation for extracting the letters and merging the files, but from you question you seem to already have that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can first so a simple substring check, and then based on that, classify the filenames into groups:

```
letters_list = ['AC', 'FO', 'CK', 'OR', 'RS', 'IK']
for letters in letters_list:
  if letters in filename:
    filename_list = filename_dict.get(letters, list())
    filename_list.append(filename)
    filename_dict[letters] = filename_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the `Path` object from `pathlib` to create a list of files whose names end with '.csv'. Then I use a function to examine each file's name for the presence of one or another of those strings that you mentioned using a regex so that I can create a list of the pairs of these strings with their associates filenames. Notice that the length of this list of pairs is 12, and that the filenames can be recovered from this.

Having made that list I can use `groupby` from `itertools` to create two-element lists of files that share those strings in the `file_kinds` list. You can merge items in these lists.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> file_kinds = ['AC', 'FO', 'CK', 'OR', 'RS', 'IK']
>>> def try_match(filename):
...     m = re.search('(%s)'%'|'.join(file_kinds), filename)
...     if m:
...         return m.group()
...     else:
...         return None
... 

>>> all_files_list = [(item, try_match(item.name)) for item in list(Path(r'C:/scratch/datafolder').glob('*.csv')) if try_match(item.name)]
>>> len(all_files_list)
12
```

Expression for extracting full paths from `all_files_list`:

```
[str(_[0]) for _ in all_files_list]

>>> for kind, files_list in groupby(all_files_list, key=itemgetter(1)):
...     kind, [str(_[0]) for _ in list(files_list)]
... 
('AC', ['C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-AC_A_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv', 'C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-AC__B_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv'])
('CK', ['C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-CK_A_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv', 'C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-CK__B_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv'])
('FO', ['C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-FO_A_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv', 'C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-FO__B_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv'])
('IK', ['C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-IK_A_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv', 'C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-IK__B_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv'])
('OR', ['C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-OR_A_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv', 'C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-OR__B_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv'])
('RS', ['C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-RS_A_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv', 'C:\\scratch\\datafolder\\UOG_001-RS__B_TOP-Accelerometer-2017-07-22T112654.csv'])
```